# Memory warnings/crashes, but not in Instruments

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-warning

I'm developing an iOS app that includes a navigable 3d map. I have a tiling/level of detail strategy that streams textures in and out as necessary, and constructs/releases map geometry as necessary based on a heightmap.

Inevitably after panning around the map, and especially on older hardware, I get a memory warning and then the app quits.

So, that in itself isn't surprising. My problem is tracking down the problem in this particular instance:

- The memory footprint seems pretty good (peak ~11MB, average ~7MB live bytes on iPad 1), and Instruments tells me I have no memory leaks. (checked many times using Heap Marking)
- But most surprising: **I can't make it actually crash or give me a memory warning in Instruments**. Which, of course, makes it very hard to track down!

Has anyone seen this before?

**EDIT**: Could it be fragmentation because of all the streaming? If so, anything I can do about it on iOS?

Comment: you might try using memory mapped files?

Comment: do you get a first memory warning?

Comment: I don't even get a first warning in instruments, no!